# To remove the comma from the output when the output is unknown using arrays and booleans

Tags: c++

How to remove the comma at the end of output. But here i do not know what is the final output since the elements of the array are inputted by the user. So last array can be either odd or even and it is unknown. And i'm allowed to use Boolean, arrays and decision making. I'm not allowed to use pointers or structures since i did not learn it.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int array[100], Number;

    cout << "\nEnter the size of an array (1-20):";

    cin >> Number;

    if (Number <= 20 && Number > 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter the elements of the array: \n";

        // For loop execution  
        // i start at 0. as long as i < Number. i++ 
        for (int i = 0; i < Number; i++)
        {
            cout << "array element " << i << ":";
            cin >> array[i];
        }

        cout << "\nEven Numbers are : ";

        // For loop execution
        for (int i = 0; i < Number; i++)
        {
            // condition and execution
            if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                cout << array[i];
                cout << " , ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;

        cout << "odd Numbers are: ";

        // For loop execution
        for (int i = 0; i < Number; i++)
        {
            // condition and execution
            if (array[i] % 2 != 0)
            {
                cout << array[i];
                cout << " , ";
            }
        }

        cout << endl;
        cout << "-------------------------------------------------";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "size is invalid" << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I look at some other programs and could not figure it out. Im a beginner so can you help me with the problem. I was requested to use two boleean variables name << odd count >> and <> and asked to solve this question using two arrays . An <>  and a << Odd Arr[]>> along with using two booleans that i mentioned.

Comment: Do two loops for each printing: first collect all entries you want to print in a vector, and then you print that vector, which makes it easy to know when you have the last element.

Comment: @Aziuth thanks but i new and didnt yet learn vector. But thanks for answering my question

Answer (score 2):

Just print comma before the element and check for first element:

```
    bool is_first = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < Number; i++)
    {
        // condition and execution
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            if(!is_first)
            {
                cout << " , ";
            }
            cout << array[i];
            is_first = false;
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to remove a trailing comma is not to print it.

redo your arrays printing into something like:

```
std::string dlm;
for (int i = 0; i < Number; i++)
{
    // condition and execution
    if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        cout << dlm << array[i];
        dlm = " , ";
    }
}
```

EDIT, moved the delimiter (accidentally put it under the loop).

Comment: thx for the help